# How can I modify my code to solve Problem 2 on LeetCode?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

Problem 2 of LeetCode provides the user with two linked lists. The digits of the linked lists are in reverse order, and the user must return the sum of the two values as a linked list.

My solution may not be the most efficient, but I want to figure out how to modify it for my own understanding of linked lists and trees.

I initialized strings to hold the digits of each linked list, then calculated the total based on both strings reversed.

I would then insert the digits of the sum into a list, and start popping the last value one at a time, adding the popped value to a new linked list until the list is empty.

However when I create my linked list called 'res', the initial value is initialized as 0. Can someone suggest a revision I can make to overcome this particular issue?

[Problem 2 of LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/description/)

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        v1 = ""
        v2 = ""
        temp = []

        while l1 and l2:
            v1 += str(l1.val)
            v2 += str(l2.val)
            l1 = l1.next
            l2 = l2.next
        
        v1 = v1[::-1]
        v2 = v2[::-1]

        total = int(v1) + int(v2)
        for char in str(total)[::-1]:
            temp.append(char)
        
        res = ListNode()
        curr = res
        while temp:
            curr.next = ListNode(temp.pop(0))
            curr = curr.next
        return res
```

Comment: You're overthinking this. Look at it this way: when you sum two big numbers on a piece of paper, don't you start by looking at their last digits and just adding those together? Then you move to the next pair (with an optional carried 1), until one of the numbers runs out of digits. Can't you do the same thing here? They even give you the digits in the right order!

Comment: @PatrickHaugh You're absolutely right, and I did end up using another solution. I made this post however mainly because I'm not too well-informed on Linked Lists and how to work with the ones you create. This was my initial attempt that I gave up on once I couldn't figure out how to solve the issue of any linked list I create requiring an initial value before I can start adding values to it via a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would take a list of values and turn them into a linked list

```
temp = [1, 2, 3, 4]

curr = None # Our lists start as empty, which is indicated by the absence of a node
for item in temp:
    curr = ListNode(item, curr)  # We create a new node that points to our current node, then 
                                 # redirect our local reference to point to that node
                                 # Remember that the right hand side is calculated first
                                 # which makes this safe
```

This would leave us with `4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1`